# Django: две функции из views.py рендерить на один html-шаблон

Tags: python, html, css, django

код из файла views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from users.models import User
from users.forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegistrationForm
from django.contrib import auth
from django.urls import reverse

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()
    context = {'form_login': form}
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    context_reg = {'form_registation': form}
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context_reg)
```

Я возвращаю обе функции на шаблон 'users/login.html'

файл forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
from users.models import User
from django import forms
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Имя',}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Пароль',}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')


class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Имя', }))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Эл. почта', }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Пароль', }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Подтвердите пароль', }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

файл login.html

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins" , sans-serif;
}
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f6f7f8;
  padding: 30px;
}

/*.navbar {*/
/*  width: 100%;*/
/*  height: 70px;*/
/*  background-color: white;*/
/*  align-items: end;*/
/*}*/

/*.navbar .container{*/
/*  margin-left: 9%;*/
/*  margin-right: 9%;*/
/*  !*наследуем высоту от родителя*!*/
/*  height: inherit;*/
/*  display: flex;*/
/*  justify-content: space-between;*/
/*  align-items: center;*/
/*}*/

.container{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  perspective: 2700px;
}
.container .cover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 98;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.container #flip:checked ~ .cover{
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
 .container .cover .front,
 .container .cover .back{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.cover .back{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container .cover::before,
.container .cover::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 12;
}
.container .cover::after{
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container .cover img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 10;
}
.container .cover .text{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 130;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.cover .text .text-1,
.cover .text .text-2{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.cover .text .text-2{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.container .forms{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.container .form-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.form-content .login-form,
.form-content .signup-form{
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 25px);
}
.forms .form-content .title{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}
.forms .form-content .title:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
.forms .signup-form  .title:before{
  width: 20px;
}
.forms .form-content .input-boxes{
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.forms .form-content .input-box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.form-content .input-box input{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.form-content .input-box input:focus,
.form-content .input-box input:valid{
  border-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.form-content .input-box i{
  position: absolute;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.forms .form-content .text{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}
.forms .form-content .text a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forms .form-content .text a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.forms .form-content .button{
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.forms .form-content .button input{
  color: #fff;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.forms .form-content .button input:hover{
  background: #6471ed;
}
.forms .form-content label{
  color: #6471ed;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.forms .form-content label:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.forms .form-content .login-text,
.forms .form-content .sign-up-text{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.container #flip{
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 730px) {
  .container .cover{
    display: none;
  }
  .form-content .login-form,
  .form-content .signup-form{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-content .signup-form{
    display: none;
  }
  .container #flip:checked ~ .forms .signup-form{
    display: block;
  }
  .container #flip:checked ~ .forms .login-form{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="flip">
    <div class="cover">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <!--<img class="backImg" src="images/backImg.jpg" alt="">-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="forms">
        <div class="form-content">
          <div class="login-form">
            <div class="title">Вход</div>
          <form action="{% url 'users:login' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-boxes">
              <div class="input-box">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                {{ form_login.username }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                {{ form_login.password }}
              </div>
              <div class="text"><a href="#">Забыли пароль?</a></div>
              <div class="button input-box">
                <input type="submit" value="Продолжить">
              </div>
              <div class="text sign-up-text">Нет аккаунта? <label for="flip">Зарегистрироваться</label></div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
        <div class="signup-form">
          <div class="title">Регистрация</div>
        <form action="{% url 'users:registration' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-boxes">
              <div class="input-box">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                {{ form_registation.username }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                {{ form_registation.email }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                {{ form_registation.password1 }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                {{ form_registation.password2 }}
              </div>
              <div class="button input-box">
                <input type="submit" value="Продолжить">
              </div>
              <div class="text sign-up-text">Уже есть аккаунт? <label for="flip">Войти</label></div>
            </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что отображаются только поля Входа, а у Регистрации пусто:

[image]

я думаю, что причина может крыться в том, что в файле views.py на шаблон login.html я возвращаю сразу две функции. Можно ли это как-то исправить, не разделяя вход и регистрацию на два шаблона?

Comment: Ну так у вас во вьюхе login не существует form_registation, а во вьюхе registration не существует form_login

Comment: (а в form_registation ещё и опечатка, но это мелочи)